# Windows Update Service Pack 1 give error 0x800f0826

Tags: windows-7, service-pack

I'm helping out a remote user that has an Apple OSX box running Parallels with Windows 7 as the guest OS.  When installing Windows 7 SP1, error 0x800f0826 is generated with no additional information.  I've found hundreds of discussion board posts related to this problem, but few are anything more than people reporting the problem.  The closest thing I've found to a common thread is that earlier versions of DriverSweeper.Net would remove some necessary video drivers that SP1 required, but I don't think my remote user is using this app (I've asked, but havent' gotten a response yet).

Does anyone have any decent information on this particular error?

Answer (score 2):

Before you kill yourself trying to fix this, try running the "System Update Readiness Tool" first.

It is often a miracle worker as it can automatically fix problems that get in the way of a successful service pack install. It can take from 15 minutes to over 2 hours to run, so if it takes a long time, do not worry, it is probably still working.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821